# Create a new transporterFleet from an existing transporterFleet

Tags: anylogic

I have a transporter type agent called **Truck**. Its population called **truck**. I added a **TransporterFleet** block to the model which is called **truckFleet**. In **truckFleet** I selected **Truck** for both **New Transporter** and **Transporter Type** sections. An agent called **trench** seizes from **truckfleet** and when it release the truck, it will allocate a value to a variable as I used `((Truck)unit).v_capacityFull = true;` in the **on release transporter** section.

Now I have another agent called **dumping**. Now this agent needs to **sieze a specefic truck** from truckFleet. one that has the following value **v_capacityFull == true**.

So I have been applying two approaches:

1. I used the **same transportFleet** which called truckFleet. But I use a dynamic Fleet section in which I typed `new truckFleet = List filter(truck, t -> v_capacity == 0);`
2. I created a **new transporterFleet** called **fullTruckFleet** and in the **new transporter** section I typed `new truckFleet = List filter(truck, t -> v_capacity == 0);` but in the transporter type I still used **Truck**.

for the first approach: I get the following errors:

[image]

and for the second option: I get the following errors:

[image]

In general, I am not happy about non of them but could not think about another approach. And I am not just interested to resolve errors but to find an approach that fulfill my intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very easy actually. I can use the same **truckFleet** but in the **Advanced** section of the **SeizeTransporter** block, in **Transporter choice condition** section, I can type `((Truck)unit).v_capacityFull == true`. :)